# Do I need the "who" in the following sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

> He smiled at this girl. This girl (who) he thought didn't exist in the
>   world.

I thought the last sentence sounded strange so I added a *who*. Or maybe it's unnecessary?

Comment: You can use *who* or *whom* or leave it blank.

Comment: *The last sentence* is not a sentence. It cannot stand on its own. It ought to be linked to the first sentence with a comma rather than a full stop.

Comment: What sounds strange to me is **didn't exist *in the world***.  It's grammatical, but slightly off, to my ear.  There could be a full stop after "didn't exist": "this girl he thought didn't exist." or simply "this girl who didn't exist." with merely an implied reference to his earlier opinion which has proven wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative pronoun **that** is often omitted in spoken English: other relative pronouns are not usually omitted. If you think that this sentence works, you can omit it:

> He smiled at this girl. This girl (that) he thought didn't exist in the world.

Comment: Q: What's 4 – 5? A: Calculate 5 – 6. (–1, yes.)

Comment: @userr2684291 Wait, what's the problem? Is it *..other relative pronoun aren't usually omitted.* ?

Comment: @user178049 The problem is that this answer isn't an answer to the posed question, just like in my example. The statement you quote is vague, but not incorrect.

Comment: @userr2684291 If pronoun in the question were "that", it wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Without the word whom it reads as if you're referring to a thought which occurred at the same time as the smile but have omitted the commas.

```
He smiled at this girl. This girl he thought didn't exist in the world.
He smiled at this girl. This girl, he thought, didn't exist in the world.
```

With the word whom it reads that up to that point in time he thought she didn't exist.

```
He smiled at this girl. This girl whom he thought didn't exist in the world.
```

You should use whom not who because it is the object of the verb think.

Also 'in the world' is unnecessary. If she doesn't exist then she doesn't exist in any location.

Comment: The he would have written 'in this world'.

Comment: Actually, you can edit your post, if you want to add more information. Btw, I disagree that it *should* be "whom". "Who" just sounds fine.

Comment: http://www.abacus-es.com/sat/case.htmlPronoun Declension
number

person

gender*

Pronouns

subject

object

who

whom

Comment: @ChrisM: for normal people, that's a rule that's honoured more in the breach than in the observance.

Comment: It's ok to use who in everyday speech but in formal writing whom should be used.